# После переноса сайта с локалки на хостинг возникла проблема

Tags: wordpress, cms, wordpress-плагины

После переноса сайта с open server на хостинг возникла данная проблема: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данная проблема на странице плагинов. То есть я не могу получить доступ к просмотру плагинов репозитории.
В чем может быть проблема? Раньше такого не было.

Comment: Поотключай все плагины перед переносом и включи дебаг в конфиге

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561

Comment: Во первых см коммент  KAGGDesign-ра. Если после правильной миграции проблема останется, то скорее всего виноват curl. В любом случае это легко проверяется на чистой установке ВП.